# Find Sub-list in a List using binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I have to use to see if smallList is a sub-list of bigList by checking that the values of smallList appear in the same order in bigList. The elements have to match sequentially too

```
int bigList[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int smallList[] = {3,4,5,6};
```

Binary Algortithm:

```
bool binarySearch(int x[],int list[],int first, int last)
{
    bool yes=true;
    bool no=false;
    int mid=(first+last)/2;
    if(x[last]>list[mid])
    {            
        binarySearch(x,list,mid,last);
    }
    else if (x[last]<list[mid])
    {
        binarySearch(x,list,first,mid);
    }
    else if (x[last]==list[mid])
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need to know how i can use/modify the above algorithm to check that smallList is a sub-list of bigList. I HAVE TO use the algorithm to figure this out.
Link to problem: https://docs.google.com/document/d/12pWWQo66-P-CMWoFH0HPWy09ws4LccGay2pKsv0XWlo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your post doesn't have a question.

Comment: I updated it, sorry guys

Comment: So you want us to solve your homework/interview question/whatever. That's not going to happen. Please convince us first that you have already put some (even better, a lot of) effort into solving the problem yourself

Comment: I have been at this for 4 hours now and i can not figure it out. Im not telling you to do my work for me, There are 2 other parts to this that i still have to do. This is worth 10% of my mark and i just can afford loosing marks. As programmers we are obviously allowed to use the internet as reference. I'm not asking for a solution, i would appreciate if you guys point me in the right direction.

Comment: The question makes no sense. It is not defined what a sublist is and it is not clear whether one or both of the lists are sorted. If the latter is not the case, binary search is not applicable

Comment: I figured it out but HEY thanks for Absolutely no help man

Answer (score 3):

The Standard Library contains `std::includes` and `std::search` algorithms for such purposes:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ios>

int main()
{
    int bigList[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int smallList[] = {3,4,5,6};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::includes(
        std::begin(bigList), std::end(bigList), 
        std::begin(smallList), std::end(smallList)
    );

    std::cout << (std::search(
        std::begin(bigList), std::end(bigList), 
        std::begin(smallList), std::end(smallList)
    ) != std::end(bigList));
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32c4aca4c5cde5d4) that prints `truetrue`.

`std::includes` checks if all elements from `smallList` are contained in `bigList`, and `std::search` checks if `smallList` is a proper subsequence of `bigList` (and returns the end iterator if it isn't).

Comment: I HAVE to use the binarySearch function to accomplish the task

Comment: This is pretty suboptimal in terms of asymptotics

Comment: @NiklasB. `std::search` has `O(Big*Small)` complexity, how much better could you get, and which algorithm would do that?

Comment: Hmm I thought at least one of the lists were sorted, in which case binary search would  yield an O(log big + small) algorithm. If that's not the case we can only get O(big + small) using any given pattern matching algorithm, but that's a less dramatic difference.